# creating a table and inserting values using cursor (PL/SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm relatively new to PL/SQL. I have written the PL/SQL code to create a table and insert few values into it based on the result fetched by another table.

```
DECLARE

nCount NUMBER;
v_sql VARCHAR2(4000);


BEGIN
SELECT count(*) into nCount FROM all_tables where table_name = 'OBJECT_ANALYSIS_T';

dbms_output.put_line(nCount);
IF(nCount <= 0) THEN

BEGIN
  v_sql:='
  create table object_analysis_t
  (
    object_type varchar2(10),
    object_name varchar2(10),
    validity varchar2(10),
    status varchar2(10),
    severity varchar2(10)
  )';
  execute immediate v_sql;
  commit;
END;

DECLARE
  c_object_type VARCHAR2(10);
  c_object_name USER_OBJECTS.OBJECT_NAME%type;
  c_validity USER_OBJECTS.STATUS%type;
  c_status VARCHAR2(5);
  c_severity VARCHAR2(10);


CURSOR c_user_objects is
  SELECT object_name,status FROM USER_OBJECTS WHERE object_type IN ('FUNCTION');


  BEGIN
    c_object_type:= 'FUNCTION';
    OPEN c_user_objects;
    LOOP
      FETCH c_user_objects INTO c_object_name, c_validity;

      IF( c_validity = 'VALID') THEN 
        c_status:= 'PASS';
      ELSIF( c_validity = 'INVALID') THEN
        c_status:= 'FAIL';
      ELSE
        c_status:= 'FAIL';
      END IF;

      EXIT WHEN c_user_objects%notfound;
      --INSERT THE VALUES IN THE CREATED TABLE
      BEGIN
      execute immediate 'INSERT INTO OBJECT_ANALYSIS_T VALUES (c_object_type, c_object_name, c_validity, c_status,c_severity) '; 
      END;

      END LOOP;
      CLOSE c_user_objects;
  END;

  END IF;
  END;
  /
```

Now when I execute the above code, The table is created but values in the variable are not inserted into the new table.

I get this error

```
ORA-00984: column not allowed here
```

any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you take a step back and explain the business problem you're trying to solve?  Creating tables at runtime in PL/SQL is generally frowned upon.  Giving someone that is new to PL/SQL a task that requires extensive use of dynamic SQL is generally a bad idea.  If you can explain the problem you're trying to solve, we may be able to help you with a better solution.  It appears, for example, that you could replace both blocks of code with a simple `SELECT` statement.

Comment: in `all_tables` there is column named `status` , This value can be `valid` or `invalid` based on this value i have to set the `status` in the new table (`object_analysis_t`) which will be `pass` or `fail`.

Comment: But what purpose does this new table serve?  Wouldn't a view on the `user_objects` table that included the pass/ fail calculation as a `CASE` statement make more sense?  So that the data is always current?  If you really want to persist the data for some reason, why are you creating the table dynamically rather than creating it at installation time with all the other objects your application uses?

Comment: no the table should be permanent because there are other applications which ll be using it. Is there any better alternative for this than creating it dynamically?

Comment: Why does it need to be a table rather than a view?  Unless you're adding something like a date that indicates when the data was persisted, it doesn't make a lot of sense to write that data to a table.  If you really, really need a table, you'd create it at installation time with all your other tables.

Answer (score 1):

You PL/SQL variable names are out of scope to the dynamic SQL statement. You need to pass the values as bind variables with the `using` clause:

```
execute immediate 'INSERT INTO OBJECT_ANALYSIS_T VALUES '
  || '(:object_type, :object_name, :validity, :status, :severity)'
  using c_object_type, c_object_name, c_validity, c_status,c_severity;
```

It's also good practice to specify the target table column names. It's even beter practice to not use dynamic SQL unless you really have to, and as Justin Cave mentioned, you would usually create schema objects in a more controlled way, not at runtime or on demand. Using dynamic SQL hides what should be compilation errors until runtime, and can be much harder to debug.

Comment: after executing by changing the values it is giving the error as `ORA-12899: value too large for column` near `execute immediate`

Comment: 'You need to pass the values as bind variables' -- by this do you mean to say declare the variables like this : `VARIABLE c_object_type varchar2(10);`

Comment: @amit - that's because your new table's columns are smaller than the user_objects columns. You already have variables defined like that in the sub-block; but making them all %type would be better too.

Comment: after giving the column names `execute immediate 'INSERT INTO OBJECT_ANALYSIS_T (OBJECT_TYPE, OBJECT_NAME, VALIDITY, STATUS, SEVERITY) VALUES '
  || '(:object_type, :object_name, :validity, :status, :severity)'
  using c_object_type, c_object_name, c_validity, c_status,c_severity;` it gives the error `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`

Comment: @amit - that looks OK; are you sure it's from that line? Did you change anything else? I realised my previous comment was ambiguous, only local variables should use %type, so I hope you didn't change the create to use that too - that sill has to specify `object_name varchar2(30)` etc.